# Remap key for tag pop

Tags: vim

I am trying to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> to `:pop`.  I have rebound my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to `:tabe` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to new shell tab.  I came up with:

```
nnoremap <C-[> :pop
```

but when I do this I get `:pop` on almost every keystroke, and even mouse clicks.

The idea being that this keymapping tacks me back up the chain of the tags list. Opposite of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: The `<esc>`key and `<c-[>` not distinguishable. See `:h escape`. You will want to come up w/ a different mapping.

Comment: @PeterRincker If you move this to an answer I'll accept it. This was what was causing the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a terminal, `<Esc>` is the same as `<C-[>`; both are represented by the same keycode.

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, differentiating this as well as many other key combinations (like Ctrl+Letter vs. Ctrl+Shift+Letter) unfortunately isn't possible today, even in GVIM. This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Comment: Thank you for the thread. This would be a great addition to Vim.